# How to convert multiclass data into binary class in python for image classification?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pycharm, pytorch

I am trying to do binary class image classification using PyTorch.I have a csv file in where my dataset classes (**V00XRKL**) are stored. The dataset has five classes but I would like to convert it into binary class using the condition like ***if V00XRKL<2*** then the ***Class =1*** ,otherwise **Class= 2**. 
Here is the example of my dataset 
[image].

For this purpose I wrote my code in this way

```
# read the csv file

classfile = pd.read_csv(csvroot)
print('df length orig:', len(classfile))

# remove the NA value from the file
df_NA = classfile.dropna(how='any', axis=0)
print('df length no NA:', len(df_NA))

# Dropout the duplicates of number from ID and Side
df_drop = df_NA.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'SIDE'])
print('df length no dup:', len(df_drop))

# reset the index
df_in = df_drop.reset_index(drop=True)
df_in.loc[df_in['V00XRKL'] < 2, 'V00XRKL'] = 1
df_in.loc[df_in['V00XRKL'] >= 2, 'V00XRKL'] = 2
#df_in.to_clipboard(sep=',')
```

After running this code I seen that my data has converted in to binary class,here is the screenshot of converted data [image].

But the problem is that whenever I try to train my cnn model I am getting this error messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Downloads/test to con.py", line 379, in <module>
    model, train_loss, valid_loss,val_acc = train_model(net,  patience, n_epochs,costFunction)
  File "/home/Downloads/test to con.py", line 165, in train_model
    loss = criterion(output, labels)
  File "/home/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 942, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2056, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1871, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:92
```

Here is my code that I used to make dataset class

```
#make a class for data
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file,root_dir, transform=None):
       # self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None)
       self.df_data= csv_file
       self.root_dir = root_dir


       self.transform = transform


    def __len__(self):
       return len(self.df_data)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.df_data['ID'].iloc[idx])+'.npy')

        patches, p_id = np.load(img_name, allow_pickle= True)


        img_class = int(self.df_data.iloc[idx,2])

        side = self.df_data.iloc[idx,1]


        if side ==1:
            image = Image.fromarray(patches['R'].astype('uint8'), 'L')                                              #[image['R':side]|image['L':side]]
        else:
            image = Image.fromarray(patches['L'].astype('uint8'), 'L')

        if self.transform is not None:
             image = self.transform(image)

        sample = {'image': image, 'grade':img_class}

        return sample
```

And this is the CNN model

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
            super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
          # Convolution 1
            self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)) # maxpolling layer 1
          # Convolution 1
            self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
            self.drop_out = nn.Dropout(0.2)
          # Fully connected
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 16 * 64, 1000)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000,2)

    def forward(self, x):
           out = self.layer1(x)
           out = self.layer2(out)
           out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
           #print(out.shape)
           out = self.drop_out(out)
           out = self.fc1(out)
           out = self.fc2(out)
           return out
```

I would appreciate  any kind of help in this regard.

Comment: My strong guess is that the problem is because you number your classes `1` and `2` instead of 0-indexing: `0` and `1`.

Comment: I agree with @Jatentaki I had also a Problem when I tried to have 1 and 2 as classes and I resolve it when i changed it to 0 and 1. this happens because when you have 1 and 2 as classes, it also expect to see 0 so that you have 3 classes altogether